# Trying to generate all sequences of specified numbers up to a max sum

Tags: c#, linq, algorithm, sequences

Given the following list of descending unique numbers (3,2,1) I wish to generate all the sequences consisting of those numbers up to a maximum sum.

Let's say that the sum should be below 10. Then the sequences I'm after are:

```
3 3 3
3 3 2 1
3 3 2
3 3 1 1 1
3 3 1 1
3 3 1
3 3
3 2 2 2
3 2 2 1 1
3 2 2 1
3 2 2
3 2 1 1 1 1
3 2 1 1 1
3 2 1 1
3 2 1
3 2
3 1 1 1 1 1 1
3 1 1 1 1 1
3 1 1 1 1
3 1 1 1
3 1 1
3 1
3
2 2 2 2 1
2 2 2 2
2 2 2 1 1 1
2 2 2 1 1
2 2 2 1
2 2 2
2 2 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 1 1 1 1
2 2 1 1 1
2 2 1 1
2 2 1
2 2
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 1 1 1 1 1
2 1 1 1 1
2 1 1 1
2 1 1
2 1
2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1
1
```

I'm sure that there's a "standard" way to generate this.

I thought of using linq but can't figure it out.
Also, I am trying a stack based approach but I am still not successful.

Any idea?

Comment: i don't think there is a standard way of even asking this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is easiest to write recursively, something which pure LINQ isn't that great for. So it's probably best to implement this as an ordinary recursive function. Pass as a parameter the amount you have left from your maximum total and every time you add en element, call the function recursively, reducing the total appropriately:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> sequences(IEnumerable<int> set, int maxTotal)
{
    foreach (int i in set.Where(x => x <= maxTotal))
    {
        yield return new int[] { i };
        foreach (var s in sequences(set.Where(x => x <= i), maxTotal - i))
            yield return (new int[] { i }).Concat(s);
    }
}

void Run()
{
    foreach (var z in sequences(new int[] { 3, 2, 1 }, 10))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            string.Join(" ", z.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray())
        );
    }
}
```

Result:

```
3
3 3
3 3 3
3 3 3 1
3 3 2
3 3 2 2
3 3 2 1
3 3 2 1 1
3 3 1
3 3 1 1
3 3 1 1 1
...
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Note that this isn't the most efficient solution.

Comment: Darnit, sorry, I deleted the comment because I saw you'd edited the code. I'm also a bit concerned this does duplicate work, for example it evaluates `sequences({2,3},6)` twice, once after starting with {2,1,1} and once after starting with {2,2}. That's fine with n=10, but without memoisation will that result in time becoming the most limiting factor in practice?

Comment: @Steve Jessop: You are right, it does indeed do duplicate work. There are certainly *much* faster ways to solve this problem.

Comment: It is not efficient indeed. My example was oversimplified. In fact the allowable sum would be far greater than a number, in a range of 100 for the sum and in a range of 1 to 10 for the numbers.

Comment: @Stecy: Perhaps you could give us some background and motivation for  the problem. It might be possible to solve it without enumerating all the possibilities.

Comment: Must you also print the numbers? Because printing is going to be the bottleneck of any algorithm. Maybe you only need to count them? If those are your limits and your requirement is to print the numbers, then you are out of luck I'm afraid - there's probably nothing faster. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Ok, here's the background. I have a line of packets having various lengths (about 4-5 types in my case, which results in having more than 1 packet per length type). The packets are measured in inches, for example there are 60, 72, 84. The length of the line is 68 feet (816 inches). I'm trying to find all the possible arrangements of those packets that would fit the line.

Comment: @Stecy: But why would you want to find all the possible arrangements? What do you need them for? Do you have an actual business problem that you need to solve? If so, what is that problem? Or is this homework? In which case, please tag it with the `homework` tag.

Comment: It is an actual business problem in the wood industry. The problem is finding the closest arrangements (2 or 3) to the line length given the different lengths of packet we have.

Comment: @Stecy: A bit like this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem : "Imagine that you work in a paper mill and you have a number of rolls of paper of fixed width waiting to be cut, yet different customers want different numbers of rolls of various-sized widths. How are you going to cut the rolls so that you minimize the waste (amount of left-overs)?"

Comment: @Stecy: You might also want to look at the Knapsack_problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: @Mark: Yep kind of, it's more of a bin packing problem, but I was looking for a quicker and simpler approach.

Comment: @Stecy: I don't think I can give you a better approach than is already on Wikipedia... bin packing is NP-complete :(

Comment: Thanks anyway. For now, I will use your solution as it is a nice start. I will use some heuristics in determining the placement as there are some rules defined for this. However, if you find a better, more efficient, algorithm let me know. ;)

Comment: @Stecy: Note also that I slightly misread your question: my solution finds up-to-and-including 10, but you asked for only up-to. The solution of course is to change `<= maxTotal` to `< max_total`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve that by building a tree. 
On each node you have a list of values. Assuming the sum of this list is less than the required sum - let's call it S -, you can build at most three children for this node: one by adding 1 to the list of this node, one by adding 2 and one by adding 3. The condition to build a child would be that the sum of the new list would still be less that S.
At the end, i.e. when you can't generate new nodes, you have all your sequences in the nodes of your tree.

EDIT: in C# my poor explanation would give sth like that:

first:

```
public class Node
{
    public Node()
    {
        Children = new List<Node>();
    }

    public static int SumMax { get; set; }

    public List<int> Values { get; set; }

    public List<Node> Children { get; set; }

    public void AddChild(int data)
    {
        if (Values.Sum() + data < SumMax)
        {
            Node child = new Node();
            child.Values = new List<int>(Values);
            child.Values.Add(data);
            Children.Add(child);

            for (int = data; i < 4; i++)
            {
                child.AddChild(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void FillSequences(List<List<int>> sequences)
    {
        if (Values.Count != 0)
        {
            sequences.Add(Values);
        }

        foreach (Node child in Children)
        {
            child.FillSequences(sequences);
        }
    }
}
```

then the main:

```
void Main()
{
    Node.SumMax = 10;
    Node root = new Node();
    root.Values = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        root.AddChild(i);

    List<List<int>> sequences = new List<List<int>>();
    root.FillSequences(sequences);

    //here you've got your sequences results in "sequences" and you can do what you want
}
```

I don't know if it is standard enough but it does roughly the job. I hope it fits your need...

**EDIT**: to avoid the generation of same sequences, we can "order" the tree: a node can't generate a child with a lower value than its one. Thus, in the AddChild method, we start the loop at "data" and not at 1.

Comment: Close but you're generating a lot of sequences that are the same but in a different order.

Comment: @Stecy: you're right, I've missed that. I have updated my code to fix that

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is "standard" as such, but it's not unusual to start at the bottom and work up.

There's 1 way to make 1.

There's 2 ways to make 2, divided into 3 categories: those starting with a 1, those starting with a 2, and those starting with a 3. The last category of course is empty.

To count the ways of making N, consider the ways of making N-1 starting with 1, the ways of making N-2 starting with 2 or 1, and the ways of making N-3 starting with 3, 2, or 1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the 'easiest' (if not the most efficient) way of doing this would be to just take your number set, and take all the permutations of it, then filter out the ones whose sum is above the cutoff point.

Comment: Permutations doesn't work because the numbers can be repeated.  ie: His number set is (3,2,1), permutations wouldn't generate (3,3).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're interested in [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29), with a bit of a twist. This function does the trick. Basically, keep adding numbers to a stack while their sum is less than your target sum, then print the stack at each step.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        GeneratePossibilites(new int[] {3, 2, 1}, 10, 0, new List<int>());
    }

    static void GeneratePossibilites(int[] array, int maxSum, int crSum, List<int> stack)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < stack.Count; ++i )
            Console.Write(array[ stack[i] ].ToString() + " ");

        int start = 0;
        if (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            start = stack[stack.Count - 1];
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        for (int i = start; i < array.Length; ++i)
            if (crSum + array[i] < maxSum)
            {
                stack.Add(i);
                GeneratePossibilites(array, maxSum, crSum + array[i], stack);
                stack.RemoveAt(stack.Count - 1);
            }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if you need the output in a specific format or not, but you can probably work with this or the other answers.